# Can not upload file in an existing folder

Tags: capistrano

I tried to upload index.html to my staging server,

`Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - //home/deploy/workspace/webApp/current/index.html`

`upload! "#{Dir.pwd}/src/index.html", "/#{current_path}/index.html"`

However, `//home/deploy/workspace/webApp/current` did exist.

And if I try to `/tmp/index.html` it works perfect.

I thought Capistrano is matured to prevent this sort of freaky strange issue T_T

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two leading slashes in your destination path:

```
//home/deploy/workspace/webApp/current/index.html
^^
```

That is an invalid path. Remove the extra leading slash and try again.

```
upload! "#{Dir.pwd}/src/index.html", "#{current_path}/index.html"
```